# How do the Skrulls have access to Cull Obsidian's DNA?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, skrulls, secret-invasion

In *Secret Invasion* episode 2, we see

> samples of various DNA projected on a screen in a Skrull lab.

These samples included several notable names, such as

> Groot and Cull Obsidian.

It's plausible to think that through all of Groot's adventures on Earth (*Infinity War*, *Endgame*, and *The Guardians of the Galaxy Holiday Special*) he may have left some DNA behind that the Skrulls picked up (such as a sliver of wood from his arm or whatever), but Cull Obsidian was killed during the battle in Wakanda in *Infinity War*. How did the Skrulls obtain his DNA?

Answer (score 5):

During the initial battle in New York, Wong opens (and then closes) a portal and cuts off one of Cull Obsidian's arms. His arm was sitting there in that park in NYC for who knows how long, but definitely long enough for some random person who happens to be a Skrull to take a DNA sample before anyone is the wiser.

Comment: Such artifacts are the responsibility of the Department of Damage Control, and DoDC probably would have been a huge target for Skrull infiltration for precisely this reason.